# Problems reading .txt file in Android

Tags: android, file, dropbox

I am trying to read a file i download from Dropbox (using Dropbox CORE API).

```
 private void downloadropboxfile(final String filename)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                File file = new File(getCacheDir(),filename);
                if(!file.exists())
                    file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info=mDBApi.getFile("/" + filename, null, outputStream, null);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

}
```

Then in another function i call the downloaddropbox function and try to read the file content on Onclick event.

```
  String filename = "info.txt";

     downloadropboxfile(filename);
     String strLine = "";
     try {
         InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),filename));
         InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
          BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

         /** Reading the contents of the file , line by line */
         while ((strLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
             mTestOutput.setText(strLine);
         }

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

My problem is that i don't get the file content immediately. I need to click the button 3-4 times in order to read the file content. What's the problem with my code?

Comment: If it is fetching over the network, a delay is to be expected. Does clicking the button and then waiting for a while help?

Comment: I have checked that and i think it's not about network delay. I get the data after i click multiple times the button.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `downloaddropboxfile`, which starts a new thread to download the file. But then you're immediately trying to read the local file (before it's downloaded).

If you haven't worked with threading before, the important thing to understand is that `downloaddropboxfile` returns almost immediately, but the thread it starts keeps running in the background. You'll need to wait for it to finish before trying to do something with the downloaded file.

Comment: How  to do  that? How  can  i wait firstly  the download  to  finish and then  to read from  the local  file?

Comment: Should i use AsyncTask with doinbackground and onpostexecute functions?